# C# windows form checking all entries then show message box

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, messagebox

Im making a C# windows form to check all entries, when all entries are valid, a message box will appear but i need help in ensuring all entries are valid and showing a message box. there's probably a easier to do all this, but might as well learn how to do all this. Here's what i have so far.

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txt_name.Text;
        string email = txt_email.Text;
        string address = txt_address.Text;
        string course = txt_course.Text;
        string phone = txt_phone.Text;


        if (name.Length < 8)
        {
            txt_name.Text = "Invalid Name";
            txt_name.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_name.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        }

        if (email.Contains('@'))
        {
            if (email.Contains(".com") || email.Contains(".COM"))
            {

                txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                txt_email.Text = "invalid Email";
                txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txt_email.Text = "invalid Email";
            txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if (address.Length < 12)
        {
            txt_address.Text = "invalid Address";
            txt_address.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_address.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
       if (course.Contains("Games Design") || course.Contains("Electronics") || course.Contains("Mobile Communications") || course.Contains("GAMES DESIGN") || course.Contains("ELECTRONICS") || course.Contains("MOBILE COMMUNICATIONS"))
        {
            txt_course.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_course.Text = "invalid Course";
            txt_course.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

       if (phone.Length < 8)
        {
            txt_phone.Text = "invalid Phone Number";
            txt_phone.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
       else
        {
            txt_phone.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The answers given are what I do except I make a validation method  of type bool and put my code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a boolean and set it to false anywhere you are failing a validation.

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txt_name.Text;
    string email = txt_email.Text;
    string address = txt_address.Text;
    string course = txt_course.Text;
    string phone = txt_phone.Text;
    bool formIsValid = true;


    if (name.Length < 8)
    {
        txt_name.Text = "Invalid Name";
        txt_name.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        formIsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txt_name.ForeColor = Color.Green;

    }

    if (email.Contains('@'))
    {
        if (email.Contains(".com") || email.Contains(".COM"))
        {

            txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            txt_email.Text = "invalid Email";
            txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            formIsValid = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        txt_email.Text = "invalid Email";
        txt_email.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        formIsValid = false;
    }

    if (address.Length < 12)
    {
        txt_address.Text = "invalid Address";
        txt_address.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        formIsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txt_address.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
   if (course.Contains("Games Design") || course.Contains("Electronics") || course.Contains("Mobile Communications") || course.Contains("GAMES DESIGN") || course.Contains("ELECTRONICS") || course.Contains("MOBILE COMMUNICATIONS"))
    {
        txt_course.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        txt_course.Text = "invalid Course";
        txt_course.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        formIsValid = false;
    }

   if (phone.Length < 8)
    {
        txt_phone.Text = "invalid Phone Number";
        txt_phone.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        formIsValid = false;
    }
   else
    {
        txt_phone.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }

    if (formIsValid)
    {
        //submit the form
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your error message here");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple thing, you can introduce a Boolean variable to denote the status, initially set it to `true`(say `IsAllValidEntries`), in case of invalid entry make it false. And check the variable at the End, if any of the condition is false the value of the boolean variable will also be false; following code will help you:

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // definitions

     bool IsAllValidEntries = true;

     if (name.Length < 8)
     {
        //code here
         IsAllValidEntries = false;
     }
     else{  }

     if (email.Contains('@'))
     {
         if (email.Contains(".com") || email.Contains(".COM"))
         {
             // your code here
         }
         else
         {
             //code here
             IsAllValidEntries = false;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         //code here
         IsAllValidEntries = false;
     }

     if (address.Length < 12)
     {
         //code here
         IsAllValidEntries = false;
     }
     else
     {
         txt_address.ForeColor = Color.Green;
     }
     if (course.Contains("Games Design") || course.Contains("Electronics") || 
     {
         txt_course.ForeColor = Color.Green;
     }
     else
     {
         //code here
         IsAllValidEntries = false;
     }

     if (phone.Length < 8)
     {
         //code here
         IsAllValidEntries = false;
     }
     else
     {
         txt_phone.ForeColor = Color.Green;
     }

     if (IsAllValidEntries)
         MessageBox.Show("Well done");
     else
         MessageBox.Show("oooops!");    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work fine, but it would be nicer in its own method, say `AllEntriesValid` which returns a boolean and, if ALL entries must be valid, can short-circuit if an invalid entry is hit, as such:

```
private bool AllEntriesValid()
{
   if (name.Length < 8)
   {
      txt_name.Forecolor = Color.Red;
      return false;
   }
   if (email.Contains('@'))
   {
      return false;
   }

  //if we get this far, no invalid entries were found, return true
  return true;
}
```

This can then be called from multiple button clicks, not just the one you've currently got - and it's much more readable and keeps your code condensed!

Then in your button code, you would simply call:

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (AllEntriesValid())
   {
      //do something now that everything is valid
   }
}
```

//EDIT: Pressed submit too soon.

Dan